# Codeigniter migration auto and key issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, migration

I am trying to create a migration file in Codeigniter but when I run it it's throwing an error and no matter what I do I cannot get it to run.

```
class Migration_Add_users extends CI_Migration {     

public function up()
{
        $this->dbforge->add_field(array(
            'USERS_id' => array(
                'type' => 'INT',
                'constraint' => 5,
                'auto_increment' => TRUE,
            ),
            'USERS_firstname' => array(
                'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                'constraint' => '100',
            ),
            'USERS_surname' => array(
                'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                'constraint' => '100',
            ),
            'USERS_email' => array(
                'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                'constraint' => '150',
                ),
            'USERS_password' => array(
                'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                'constraint' => '150',
                ),
            'USERS_password' => array(
                'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                'constraint' => '150',
                ),
            'USERS_created' => array(
                'type' => 'DATETIME',
                ),
        ));

        $this->dbforge->create_table('users');
        $this->dbforge->add_key('USERS_id', TRUE);
    }

    public function down()
    {
        $this->dbforge->drop_table('users');
    }
}
```

this is the error

```
Error Number: 1075
Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key
```

**table**

```
CREATE TABLE `users` ( 
`USERS_id` INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`USERS_firstname` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
`USERS_surname` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
`USERS_email` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL, 
`USERS_password` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL, 
`USERS_created` DATETIME NOT NULL ) DEFAULT 
CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: set USERS_id as the primary key

Comment: I needed to run the dbforge->add_key before the dbforge->create_table - dam it! There must be a way to add this to the dbforge->add_field array

Comment: would it be that you need to add the key before the create table directive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I needed to run the

```
dbforge->add_key
```

before the

```
dbforge->create_table
```

There must be a way to add this to the

```
dbforge->add_field
```

array

Answer (score 1):

```
'USERS_password' => array(
     'type' => 'VARCHAR',
     'constraint' => '150',
),
```

appears twice.